# Lock AVFoundation Camera rotation during recording phase

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, avfoundation

I am developing a Flutter App which uses a Texture to render a native AVFoundation video stream into the Flutter part of my app.

The problem I am facing now is that in portrait everything looks fine. I am capturing everything with AVCaptureSession, add a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to it and set the videoOrientation to .portrait

```
captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
for connection in videoOutput.connections {
    connection.videoOrientation =  .portrait
}
```

If I now clockwise change the orientation of my iPad two things happen:
My Flutter UI changes to landscape, as expected, and rotates the Texture I am painting on counterclockwise. And because the iOS part detects my device orientation change it also rotates my video output by 90 degrees counterclockwise. That results in the arrow pointing to the left side instead of pointing upwards (as it does in real life)

[image]

Now I could of course just change the videoOrientation to adjust for that, add some logic where I use the current device orientation and then replace the call to ".portrait" above with:

```
connection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
```

This works. The arrow is again pointing upwards. I provide a switch case for all orientations and should be happy.

But somehow this feels wrong.
Changing the orientation back just because my camera and flutter are both rotating seems dumb. Also: I haven't tested it yet but do I need to restart the capture session when I change the configuration?

Thus:

Is there a configuration somewhere in AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureSession or AVCaptureDeviceInput where I can **lock** the camera rotation just *as if I would to it in my device settings* to stop the incoming camera stream from being rotated and thus having to change it back in AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?

Another issue I found is that with my setup of painting on a Flutter Texture: My native Swift code does not have a View - so I can't lock that orientation.